# Filtering tsv file to get top 3 occurrences based on a column value

Tags: python, parsing, bioinformatics, csv

I need to filter through a Blast result from a .tsv file.
The parameters of the filter are:

1. keep only E values < 10E-20, ignore the others
2. for each contig, save the top 3 Blast results. There aren't necessarily 3 for each contig and a lot of contigs have more than 3.

e values are in the third column.

The file is saved in this format as a .tsv

```
contig-001      [Enterobacteria phage G4 sensu lato]          9.01988e-168    5418    GCATAC
contig-001      [Enterobacteria phage ID18 sensu lato]        9.97265e-167    5418    GCATACGAAAAGACAGAATCTC
contig-002      [Enterobacteria phage ID2 Moscow/ID/2001]     1.10261e-165    5418    GCATACGAAAAGAC
contig-002      [Enterobacteria phage phiX174 sensu lato]     3.31985e-162    5418 GACTGATCGCAGT
contig-002      [Enterobacteria phage ID2 Moscow/ID/2001]     7.92015e-156    5418    GCATACGAAAAGAC
contig-002      [Enterobacteria phage ID18 sensu lato]        2.38469e-152    5418    GCATACGAAAAGAC
contig-003      [Enterobacteria phage ID2 Moscow/ID/2001]     1.08293e-112    5418    GCATACGAAAAGAC
contig-003      [Sweetpotato badnavirus A]                    0.000593081     6592 CATCGTAGCTGAT
contig-003      [Dahlia mosaic virus]                         0.000593081     6592    CAAGAAGATAGAGAGTCCCACA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the results you want to save are the nucleotide sequences (final column), this should work:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

threshold = 10E-20

data = defaultdict(dict)
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for contig, _ignore, e, _id, nuc in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'):
        contig = int(contig.split('-')[1])
        e = float(e)
        if e < threshold: continue
        data[contig][e] = nuc
        if len(data[contig]) > 3: data[contig].pop(min(data[contig]))

for contig,d in data.items():
    for e in sorted(d):
        print(contig, e, d[e])
```